# How to bind the value of slider from C# code in windows phone 8.1..?

Tags: binding, slider, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I want to bind a custom seek bar to the position of media element.

From XAML we can achieve it by

```
 Value="{Binding ElementName=mediaElement, Path=Position, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter}}"
```

where FormatConverter is a converter class written to convert mediaElement object to slider value during binding.

But I am creating the media element from code, so I want to write C# code to achieve the above. How to do it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx). I think this should work, if done like this:

```cs
 Binding myBind = new Binding() { ElementName = "mediaElement", Path = new PropertyPath("Position"), Converter = this.Resources["FormatConverter"] as IValueConverter, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
 mySlider.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, myBind);
```

Of course you need to clarify which *Resources* you use - page's or app's.